# Why is API call returning null after succesfully adding everything correctly to my list?

Tags: c#, api, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using an API to show every pokemon in the pokedex, however after I add the JSON returned values to my public `List<Data> pokemonDataList` by calling the API with `pokemon.results[i].url` the `@if (pokemon != null)` statemen shows that `pokemon` is null again. I tried the debuggin the code and it shows how its getting all the values from the API call, but somehow after it finishes it sets everything back to null?

`

```
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization
@inject HttpClient Client
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using System.Net.Http
@inject HttpClient Http


@if (pokemon != null)  //Shows null, does not enter here
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pokemon.results.Length; i++)
    {


        <div class="div2">

            <p>@pokemon.results[i].name</p>

            @if (pokemonDataList != null)
            {
                <img src="@pokemonDataList[i].sprites.front_default" width="250px" height="250px" />
            }

        </div>
    }

}

@code {
    public Rootobject pokemon { get; set; }
    Data pokemonData;
    public List<Data> pokemonDataList { get; set; } = new List<Data>();



    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() // Orria kargatzerakoan erakutsiko du
    {
        await GetPokemon();

    }

        async Task GetPokemon()
    {

        pokemon = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>(Endpoints.GetPokemonById());
      
            for (int i = 0; i < pokemon.results.Length; i++)
            {
                pokemonDataList.Add(await GetPokemonData(i)); // Gets every pokemon on the list 1154
            }
        
    }


    async Task<Data> GetPokemonData(int i)
    {
   
        return await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Data>(pokemon.results[i].url);

    }



}
```

`

I tried various `if(!null)` and `while(!null)` but it doesn't seem to work

Edit: After debugging it and changing `@if (pokemon != null)` to `@if (pokemon == null)` it looks like the methods are executed afterwards loading the html, despite putting await on the methods.

Comment: This doesn't look like the real/complete code because, as posted, it "should have worked".

Comment: In regard of the afterward execution that's because the html code is indipendent from the c# code that calls async functions, so the html just tries to load the controls in the moment that 'pokemon != null' it enters the code right away, but in that moment 'pokemondatalist' could still be null so no data shown, I suggest changing that 'pokemon != null' into 'pokemondatalist != null'

Comment: Maybe just check whether the list is null or empty (count is zero), instead of whether Pokemon is null. The list is what you need to have data right? If it also resets the list then I think the problem might be that Blazor is reloading the whole page for some reason, resetting all the variable. Hard to say without seeing the full code.